# iOS libSystem.dylib symbolic link to libSystem.B.dylib

Tags: ios, filesystems

In a jailbroken iPhone, I can see that there is a dylib in /usr/lib/LibSystem.dylib that is a symbolic link to libSystem.B.dylib. However if I tried to search for the file, it does not seem to exist

```
find / -iname libSystem.B.dylib
```

Does anyone know where libSystem.B.dylib is located?